# Qt multiple widget in QHeader of TreeWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I want to add multiple buttons and a label inside the header of a tree widget.
This is what I want : [wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHA3F.png).
This is what I tried so far :

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys


class Header(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, orientation, parent=None):
        super(Header, self).__init__(orientation, parent)

        self.layout_header = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button text')
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button text')
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('label')
        self.layout_header.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout_header.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.layout_header.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout_header)


class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        item0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["Item 0"])
        item1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["Item 1"])
        self.addTopLevelItem(item0)
        self.addTopLevelItem(item1)
        self.createHeader()

    def createHeader(self):
        header = Header(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.setHeader(header)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TreeWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I don't have any errors, but it doesn't work as well. Is it even possible to do that ?
Thank you

Comment: You probably have to explicitly declare the minimum height (for instance, `setMinimumHeight(self.layout_header.sizeHint().height())`). But, considering that you're completely overriding the purpose and display of the header, I don't really see the point of this: can't you just add the "header" as a separate widget, and include it along with the table within a vertical layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) said, I needed to declare a minimum height in order to see it.
answer :

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys


class Header(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, orientation, parent=None):
        super(Header, self).__init__(orientation, parent)

        self.layout_header = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button text')
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button text')
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('label')
        self.layout_header.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout_header.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.layout_header.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setMinimumHeight(50)
        self.setLayout(self.layout_header)


class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        item0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["Item 0"])
        item1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["Item 1"])
        self.addTopLevelItem(item0)
        self.addTopLevelItem(item1)
        self.createHeader()

    def createHeader(self):
        header = Header(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.setHeader(header)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TreeWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```